# ApplePay JS fails before onpaymentauthorized

Tags: safari, promise, applepay, applepayjs

I'm trying to set up Apple Pay on our website and having trouble getting the "onpaymentauthorized" to fire. Everything is working up to that point, the sheet comes down and the other handlers fire and respond as expected. However once authenticate the final payment the sheet displays "Payment Not Completed" and asks for for my password again.

I've seen a lot of people see a similar error on the merchant validation when the url of the requestURI doesn't match the url submitted for validation but I already dealt with that issue.

is there any way I could see more information on why Apple Pay might be failing?

Comment: did You manage to solve it? I've got the same problem :c

Comment: Struggling so hard with this as well... Error reporting apparently burns apple engineers...